# Why setPosition work in some condition but doesn't work in other condition?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.17

i make a game let's say ThrowBall, the Player can pick up the ball spawned and throw it into target get the score added then the ball return it's position and repeat. The problem is when Ball dragged by Player (i make the Ball as child of Player) into target, the Ball return it's position correctly into desired position, but the odd happens when it collided after i send the Ball into target by applying impulse it won't return the ball into desired position, why is this happening?

i'm running this game for android, i'm running this code in VS'17 using cocos2d-x-3.17. I tried changing impulse into force, moveby. I tried making the ball stop (setVelocity to zero before setPosition). I tried changing Point into Vect, vec2. I tried to break point debug, the code do read setPosition but do nothing.

```
GameScene.cpp
bool GameScene::init()
{
    //////////////////////////////
    // 1. super init first
    if ( !Layer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }

auto pickupListener = EventListenerPhysicsContact::create();
pickupListener->onContactBegin = CC_CALLBACK_1(GameScene::onContactBegin, this);
Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher()->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(pickupListener, this);
return true;
}

bool GameScene::onContactBegin(cocos2d::PhysicsContact &contact)
{
PhysicsBody *a = contact.getShapeA()->getBody();
PhysicsBody *b = contact.getShapeB()->getBody();

if (
    (BALL_COLLISION_BITMASK == a->getCollisionBitmask() && PLAYER_COLLISION_BITMASK == b->getCollisionBitmask()) ||
    (BALL_COLLISION_BITMASK == b->getCollisionBitmask() && PLAYER_COLLISION_BITMASK == a->getCollisionBitmask())
    )
{
    // make the ball follow Player
    isfollow = true;
}
else if (
    (BALL_COLLISION_BITMASK == a->getCollisionBitmask() && TARGET_COLLISION_BITMASK == b->getCollisionBitmask()) ||
    (BALL_COLLISION_BITMASK == b->getCollisionBitmask() && TARGET_COLLISION_BITMASK == a->getCollisionBitmask())
    )
{
    isfollow = false;
    // add score
    score++;
    __String *tempScore = __String::createWithFormat("%i", score);

    scoreLabel->setString(tempScore->getCString());

    // return spawn ball
    ball->returnPos();
    return false;
}
void GameScene::throwBall() {
if (isfollow == true) {
    isfollow = false;
    ball->getSprite()->getPhysicsBody()->applyImpulse(Vec2(100000, 100000));
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
}

Ball.h
class Ball
{
public:
Ball(cocos2d::Layer *layer);
cocos2d::Sprite *getSprite() { return randomSpawn; };
void returnPos();

private:
cocos2d::Size visibleSize;
cocos2d::Vec2 origin;
cocos2d::Sprite *randomSpawn;
};

Ball.cpp
Ball::Ball(cocos2d::Layer *layer)
{
visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();
randomSpawn = Sprite::create("res/ball.png");
randomSpawn->setPosition(Vec2(400, 80));

auto randomBallBody = PhysicsBody::createCircle(randomSpawn->getContentSize().width / 2);
randomBallBody->setCollisionBitmask(BALL_COLLISION_BITMASK);
randomBallBody->setContactTestBitmask(true);
randomBallBody->setGravityEnable(false);
randomSpawn->setPhysicsBody(randomBallBody);

layer->addChild(randomSpawn);
}

void Ball::returnPos()
{
randomSpawn->setPosition(Vec2(400, 80));
}
```

i want to make the object (Ball) return position when collided into Target and repeat. i'm sorry if the format is a mess, i'm new here, also it's not my full code, it's actually works fine i can run it, but only the setPosition won't work

Comment: this is just a guess but are you sure that `PhysicsBody` is not updating the position of the attached `Node` on each update so that you set it but it's then reset by physics simulation?

Comment: `__String` is a reserved identifier. Rename your class.